# AES/GCM (AES-128-GCM) authentication-tag differs in C# and Ruby

Tags: c#, ruby, openssl, bouncycastle, aes-gcm

I'm trying to generate a authentication-tag in C# which I already generated in Ruby (for testing purposes). However the results are different, but as far as I can see,the inputs are equal.

In Ruby 2.0 using OpenSSL 1.0.1c (Ubuntu 13.04):

```
require 'openssl'
require 'base64'
iv = Base64.decode64('kEWio77T7qWdytrIbUmRxA==')
key = Base64.decode64('FnUoIZvBUzC1Q/rn5WMi7Q==')
aad = Base64.decode64('/tTP07sPkoX8gah60eH89w==')
cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('aes-128-gcm').encrypt
cipher.iv = iv
cipher.key = key
cipher.auth_data = aad
cipher.final
tag = Base64.strict_encode64(cipher.auth_tag)
```

The resulting (encoded) tag is `ie74XTWtSLNad0BKdrhvmQ==`

In C# using BouncyCastle (snippet):

```
var iv = Convert.FromBase64String("kEWio77T7qWdytrIbUmRxA==");
var key = Convert.FromBase64String("FnUoIZvBUzC1Q/rn5WMi7Q==");
var aad = Convert.FromBase64String("/tTP07sPkoX8gah60eH89w==");
var cipher = new GcmBlockCipher(new AesFastEngine());
var parameters = new AeadParameters(new KeyParameter(passkey), 128, iv, aad);
cipher.Init(true, parameters);
var cipherText = new byte[cipher.GetOutputSize(0)];
cipher.DoFinal(cipherText, 0);
var tag = Convert.ToBase64String(cipher.GetMac());
```

The resulting tag in C# is `sawCcwM1T8sGl5y6VT0CHA==`

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance for your response!

Comment: What is 'passkey'? Is that a typo, or is the wrong key being passed?

Comment: Nevermind, it's a typo, see answer below.

Answer (score 8):

Okay, I installed ruby 2.0.0 and did some tests.

First of all, to replicate your original output "ie74XTWtSLNad0BKdrhvmQ==" in C#, set the IV in C# to "new byte[12]".

The reason that works, is that in the ruby code setting cipher.key clears whatever IV you set,  so the effective IV is the default all-zeroes of default length (96 bits for GCM). So you should set the IV after the key.

If we change the ruby code to do that, then the output changes to "d1tAJ6Js94tSuPNbds0EJw=="; still not a match. To reproduce this value in C#, truncate the IV to 12 bytes, i.e. "kEWio77T7qWdytrI", and the output now matches.

From this I infer that openssl/EVP is truncating any IV you give it. That shouldn't strictly be necessary, as GCM does support longer IVs, but 96 bits is in some sense the "preferred" length; I'm not sure where that policy is being enforced here.

Comment: Thanks!! Changing the IV in C# does indeed give me the same result as in Ruby. However since the C# part is not mine to change and I fail to find where Ruby caps the IV could you point me to where Ruby truncates the IV? Thanks again!

Comment: Nevermind, I found OpenSSL uses the default iv-length of 12. And Ruby does not yet provide the interface to change this length.